# MongoDB - Sum value in nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an object looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "import_type" : "MANUAL_UPLOAD",
        "supplier" : "jabino.de",
        "unit_price" : "0"
    },
    "statuses" : [ 
        {
            "status" : "DUPLICATED",
            "count" : 14
        }, 
        {
            "status" : "BLACKLISTED",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "status" : "USABLE",
            "count" : 2239
        }, 
        {
            "status" : "INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS",
            "count" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "status" : "DUPLICATED",
            "count" : 14
        }, 
        {
            "status" : "BLACKLISTED",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "status" : "USABLE",
            "count" : 2239
        }, 
        {
            "status" : "INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

How I can sum all the `count` in the `statuses` array which has the same `status` without losing keys-values in `_id`. E.g. in this case

- Duplicated: 28
- Blacklisted: 4
- Usable: 4478
- Invalid email address: 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below [**`aggregation`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QPRDjPxFNem)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$statuses" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "statuses": "$statuses.status"
    },
    "count": { "$sum": "$statuses.count" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id._id",
    "statuses": {
      "$push": {
        "status": "$_id.statuses",
        "count": "$count"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: 2 more mins mate